# Increment session array

Tags: php

How do I increment an array value with session

```
<?php
session_start();

$my_array=array(5,9,3);
$_SESSION['animals']=$my_array;
$_SESSION['animals'][0]= $_SESSION['animals'][0]+1;
echo "animals=". $_SESSION['animals'] [0];

$_SESSION['views']=$_SESSION['views']+1;
echo "Views=". $_SESSION['views'];

echo "<form method='post' action='realsession.php'>
 <input type='submit'>
  </form>";
?>
```

Views works fine, every time I hit submit it adds 1. However animals gives me 6 regardless of hitting submit. So how do I increment the array value?

thanks

Answer (score 4):

Try with:

```
session_start();

if ( !isset($_SESSION['animals']) ) {
  $_SESSION['animals'] = array(5,9,3);
}
$_SESSION['animals'][0]++;
```

Comment: If you find my answer helpful, remember to mark it with tick on the left.

Answer (score 0):

Every time the script runs, you're setting `$_SESSION["animals"][0]` is being set to 5:

```
$myarray = array(5,9,3);
```

And you're setting that to animals. Check if it's set by using `isset();`

Answer (score 0):

You are resetting the array value for `animals` every time the script runs and then incrementing the value that you just set. Remove the following lines:

```
$my_array=array(5,9,3);
$_SESSION['animals']=$my_array;
```

Answer (score 0):

With this bellow

```
$my_array=array(5,9,3);
```

You give initial values.

You need to check if $_SESSION has stored array already. 
so below that line, add

```
if(isset(SESSION['animals'] && count(SESSION['animals'])!=0){
 $my_array=SESSION['animals'];
}
```